# How to use a private key obtained from a database pem format phpseclib

Tags: rsa, phpseclib

I have stored some pem files in a database, I now wish to use this to load the key in order to ssh into the box in question. however when my code reaches the $key->load( $pub ); line in my code it errors. the code was previously working by having the keys as strings in the files but prefer to have them in the database as it'll be easier to maintain as more keys are required.

I'm using i think phpseclib as there is no loadKeys function in the RSA file. Code works when the key is pasted into the script. I pasted the code into the database directly using phpmyadmin. My dev machine is Win 10 but when live It will be on an internal linux server

```
$lightsail = new lightsail();
$pub = $lightsail->getPemByName();

$pub = str_replace("\r", '', $pub ); // Noticed key returned had \r\n so corrected it but still fails
$key = new RSA();
$key->load( $pub );
```

Error i see is as follows

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toBytes() on string in something\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php on line 724
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function toBytes() on string in something\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php on line 724
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2199  430880  {main}( )   ...\dequeue.php:0
2   40.8792 1169040 backup->backupDatabase( )   ...\dequeue.php:181
3   76.7275 2748016 phpseclib\Crypt\RSA->load( ???, ??? )   ...\my.class.php:986
```

I'm thinking that it is the paste of the pem into phpmyadmin is the issue here? I've been unable to find any examples which use $key->load() instead of $key->loadKey() with a pem file and even less of using a pem key in a database.

My next approach will be to load the file contents if this approach is after all a dead end.

Comment: Does the PEM you're trying to load from the DB start off with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`? Does it end with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`? Also, `$key->load()` doesn't exist in phpseclib 1.0 / 2.0. The docs make no mention of it so I'm not sure why you'd be using it..

Comment: yes it starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY ----- and ends with above too. Code was working with $key->load() and function exists in phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php from line 647. Code worked when i loaded the key from the file so refactoring accordingly.

Comment: idk what version of phpseclib you're using that has that line. It's not in the latest 2.0 release: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.21/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L647 Anyway, I'd say check to see that what you're getting from `file_get_contents($path)` matches what you're getting from the DB. If it ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` then I guess the issue isn't due to the column size being too small...

Comment: Good point on compare but now I've got it working with loading the file direct I dont need to have the pen in the db thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In the end i loaded it from the file ( $pub = file_get_contents($path);), this worked.